# Automapper configuration to ignore a destination class's base member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

```
ViewModel:
Class BaseViewModel
{
  public string ViewOnlyProperty{get; set;}
  ...
}

Class VmClass<T,A>:BaseViewModel where T:IVmShared A:IVmSpecific
{
  ...
}

DomainModel:
Class BaseDomainModel
{
  ...
}

Class DomainClass<T,A>:BaseDomainModel where T:IDomainShared A:IDomainSpecific
{
  ...
}

Automapper:

Mapper.CreateMap<BaseDomainModel, BaseViewModel>()
.Include<IDomainClass<IDomainShared,IDomainSpecific>, VmClass<IVmShared,IVmSpecific>>()
// Included other concrete classes implements Domain and View models interfaces
.ForMember(x => x.ViewOnlyProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());

 Mapper.CreateMap<IDomainClass<IDomainShared,IDomainSpecific>, VmClass<IVmShared,IVmSpecific>>()
.ForMember(x => x.ViewOnlyProperty, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```

I have the same configurations for ViewModel to Domain mappings. But I am getting the below exception after `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();`

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type

VmClass`2 -> DomainClass`2 (Source member list)
VmClass`2[[IVmShared],[IVmSpecific]] -> DomainClass`2[[IDomainShared],[IDomainSpecific]] (Source member list)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ViewOnlyProperty
```

Why I am getting exception for viewmodel property when it's validating viewModel->DomainModel mapping, where destination doesn't have this property at all in the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause for this issue. It was:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<IDomainClass<IDomainShared,IDomainSpecific>, VmClass<IVmShared,IVmSpecific>>()
.ForMember(x => x.ViewOnlyProperty, opt => opt.Ignore()).ReverseMap();
```

ReverseMap() doesn't work as ViewOnlyProperty doesn't exist in the destination. But Automapper was trying to map the "ViewOnlyProperty" from domain to view model, because of the reverse mapping was done on the same CreateMap(). Issue is fixed by splitting the mapping to:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<IDomainClass<IDomainShared,IDomainSpecific>, VmClass<IVmShared,IVmSpecific>>()
.ForMember(x => x.ViewOnlyProperty, opt => opt.Ignore());

 Mapper.CreateMap<VmClass<IVmShared,IVmSpecific>,IDomainClass<IDomainShared,IDomainSpecific>>();
```